# How to apply changes to pandas groupby based on values from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas groupby series with 3 columns and I would like to make a change on third column according to values from another pandas dataframe

```
Data1                               Data2(unique names)

name    col1    col2                name   col
a       10      -0.2                x      0.002
b       80      0.3                 a      0.004
a       72      1.1                 b      0.007
a       54      0.8                 ... 
b       90     -3.2
```

create pandas dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Data2)
```

and groupby the first dataframe

```
df1Groupby = df1.groupby(df1.keys()[0])
```

get the rows in df2 with common name as in df1

```
common = {}
for i in df2[df2.keys()[0]]:
    if i in df1[df1.keys()[0]].unique():
        common[i] = df2[df2.keys()[0]==i][df2.keys()[1]].values
dfcommon = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(common)
```

now I want to change col2 in Data1 for each names as

> col2 = col2 + col1 * col

defining a function

```
def my_func(group, amt):
    group[group.keys()[2]] = group[group.keys()[2]] + group[group.keys()[1]] * amt
    return group
```

and then in the main call the function

```
for i in dfcommon.index:
    df1Groupby.get_group(i).apply(my_func, dfcommon.loc[i].values[0],axis=1)
```

but then I get the following error

> TypeError: apply() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

not sure if my approach is the right way and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an simple as using [pandas.Series.map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html). You'll be creating a mapping between 'name' and 'col'. You don't need to 'merge' (join) the two data frames in this case as you're only interested to retrieve one value from the second data frame.

```
# create a mapper
mapper = Data2.set_index('name')['col']
mapped_value = Data1['name'].map(mapper)

# crete new column
data1['new_column'] = data1['col1'] + data1['col2'] * mapped_value
```

Hope this is what you're trying to achieve. If not please provide more detail and desired output!

Comment: wow! I didnt know about series.map. It did work with only 3 lines of code!! really appreciate your answer

Comment: you can make it a one liner if you want! :)
Also, map is much faster and hassle-free than merge the two data frames, highly recommended for these sort of operation!